# Spark multiple dataframe saves

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, functional-programming

I have a spark job that creates a data frame that I save down to HDFS.  What I would like to do is to save a subset of that data frame to another place, but I want to be performant about this.

The only transformation I have is the save itself...every other element of code for the spark job is an action.  I do not cache the data frame.  I am concerned that creating drop actions on a new data frame from the old one will undergo all the original data frames transformations again.

For example, I have something like:

```
val df = hiveContext.read.json("hdfs://HOSTNAME:PORT/user/spark/data/in/*")

val df2 = df.withColumn("new_column", some_udf("old_column")).drop("old_column")
.
.
.

val final_df = df10.withColumn("newest_column", another_udf("old_column2")).drop("old_column2")

val subset_df = final_df.drop("this_column")
                        .drop("that_column")
                        .drop("another_column)

final_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("json").save(hdfs_dir)
subset_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("json").save(hdfs_dir2)
```

But lets assume that `some_udf` is actually really compute intensive.  I don't want it to run twice.  Thus my question is:

Should I `final_df.cache()` before I declare `subset_df` and calling the saves to make sure that it doesn't perform the transformation of the udf again?

Something like:

```
val df = hiveContext.read.json("hdfs://HOSTNAME:PORT/user/spark/data/in/*")

val df2 = df.withColumn("new_column", some_udf("old_column")).drop("old_column")
.
.
.

val final_df = df10.withColumn("newest_column", another_udf("old_column2")).drop("old_column2")

val subset_df = final_df.drop("this_column")
                        .drop("that_column")
                        .drop("another_column)

final_df.cache()  // This is the only new line

final_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("json").save(hdfs_dir)
subset_df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("json").save(hdfs_dir2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cache:

```
val final_df = df10.withColumn(...)
val subset_df = final_df.drop(...)
final_df.cache()
```

before first action otherwise it will execute twice (as you suspect).

Comment: "Will" execute twice, or "could" execute twice? My impression is that it's the latter.

Comment: @MatthewGraves I think it will. Why would it execute only once?

Comment: Should I df2.cache after the first udf, which is still an action that won't be called until save or cache, or should I final_df.cache() after declaration of all actions but before calling the first transformation?  In other words, where should I cache?

Comment: After declaration, before action.

Comment: Just a warning: calling `cache` won't work if you don't use the RDD returned by this method. It has no side-effect, it just returns a new RDD which wraps the previous one with a caching behaviour

Comment: @fingerspitzen Done

Comment: @Dici cache __has__ side effect (it returns this)

Comment: @LostInOverflow mm, actually you're right, but I still think it's a bad thing to rely on it. It's anti-pattern in functional style, and even in Spark things like `SparkContext.broadcast` are just wrappers around the original object, and I think this is just how it should be.